# Given $a$ and $ b$, is there a general elementary solution for $a^x + a^{1/x}= b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My intuition tells me I need to factor the left side to isolate the variable. But even if I could think of some function $a^{f(x)}$ to factor out of the left hand side, I need to pick an $f(x)$ such that it removes the variable under subtraction of $x$ and $1/x$. What I mean is there is no function $f(x)$ such that both $x-f(x)$ and $1/x-f(x)$ removes $x$. If $ f(x) = x$ then $ x-f(x) $ is $ 0 $ but it compounds the problem for the next factor. Is there an elementary solution for $x$ in terms of $a$ and $ b$ that solves this general equation? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The equation is $y^{x^2}+y=b$ if $a^\frac1x=y$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not think that any closed form exist for the solution of this interesting equation; this means that numerical methods will be required.

However, may be, we could try to *approximate* the solution considering that we look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=a^x+a^{\frac{1}{x}}-b$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\left(a^x-\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}\right) \log (a)\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\log (a) \left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}} \log (a)}{x^4}+\frac{2
   a^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^3}+a^x \log (a)\right)$$ I shall assume that $a>1$.

The first derivation cancels at a point $x_*$ solution of $x^2 a^x=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and we have
$$f''(x_*)=\frac{a^{x_*} \log (a) }{x_*^2}\left(\left(x_*^2+1\right) \log (a)+2 x_*\right)$$ which is always positive.

So, if $f(x_*) \lt 0$, there will be two roots $x_{\text{left}}$ and $x_{\text{right}}=\frac 1 {x_{\text{left}}}$ with
$x_{\text{left}}
 \leq x_* \leq x_{\text{right}}$.

A simple *overestimate* of the largest solution is given by $$x_0=\frac{\log (b)}{\log (a)}\implies f(x_0)=\exp\left(\frac{\log ^2(a)}{\log (b)} \right) > 0$$ Since $f''(x_0) >0$, by Darboux theorem, the solution would be reached without any overshoot of the solution.

The first iterate of Newton method would given as
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{x_0^2 \left(a^{x_0}+a^{\frac{1}{x_0}}-b\right)}{\left(x_0^2 \,a^{x_0}-a^{\frac{1}{x_0}}\right)   \log (a)}$$

Just for illustration, I tried for a few  values of $a$ and $b=1234$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & x_0 & x_1 & \text{exact} \\
 1.5 & 17.555188 & 17.553143 & 17.553142 \\
 2.0 & 10.269127 & 10.267876 & 10.267875 \\
 2.5 & 7.7682944 & 7.7672993 & 7.7672989 \\
 3.0 & 6.4790976 & 6.4782236 & 6.4782232 \\
 3.5 & 5.6818539 & 5.6810475 & 5.6810471 \\
 4.0 & 5.1345633 & 5.1337976 & 5.1337972 \\
 4.5 & 4.7324800 & 4.7317396 & 4.7317392 \\
 5.0 & 4.4226721 & 4.4219476 & 4.4219471 \\
 5.5 & 4.1754065 & 4.1746914 & 4.1746909 \\
 6.0 & 3.9726405 & 3.9719304 & 3.9719299 \\
 6.5 & 3.8027609 & 3.8020526 & 3.8020521 \\
 7.0 & 3.6579367 & 3.6572277 & 3.6572273 \\
 7.5 & 3.5326843 & 3.5319728 & 3.5319722 \\
 8.0 & 3.4230422 & 3.4223267 & 3.4223262 \\
 8.5 & 3.3260730 & 3.3253523 & 3.3253517 \\
 9.0 & 3.2395488 & 3.2388219 & 3.2388214 \\
 9.5 & 3.1617475 & 3.1610137 & 3.1610131 \\
 10.0 & 3.0913152 & 3.0905738 & 3.0905732
\end{array}
\right)$$ which does not look bad at all (at least to me !).

For sure, we could do much better using a single iteration of Halley or Householder methods; I shall not write the formulae (they are quite messy) but extremely simple if you want to put them in a spreadsheet.